# What is the adjective for someone who pretends?

Tags: word-meaning

What is the ***adjective*** for someone who pretends? *Pretender* is *noun*. Is it **pretentious**? But the meaning of it is:

---

**pretentious** */pri-ˈten(t)-shəs/*

*adjective*

1:  characterized by pretension: such as

- making usually unjustified or excessive claims (as of value or
  standing)

  > the pretentious fraud who assumes a love of culture that is alien to 
  >   him — *Richard Watts*
- expressive of affected, unwarranted, or exaggerated importance, worth, or stature

  > pretentious language pretentious houses

2
:  making demands on one's skill, ability, or means :  ambitious

> the pretentious daring of the Green Mountain Boys in crossing the lake — *Amer. Guide Series: Vt.*

**pretentiously** *adverb*

**pretentiousness** *noun*

*Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two words though *sounding* similar have vey different roots and meanings

> **pretend** - praetendre (*Latin*) stretch forth claim
>
> **pretentious** - (*French*) pretentieux + (*English*) pretension

The word you may be looking for is

> **fake(r)** - (*adj*) [13. designed to deceive or cheat; not real; counterfeit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/faker)

but there may be several different ways to describe *one who pretends* depending on the context

> He is a *pretender* to the throne.
>   He makes a *false claim* to the throne.
>   He makes an *illegitimate claim* to the throne.
>
> He is *pretending* to be doctor.
>   Hs is *impersonating* a doctor.
>   He is *acting like* a doctor.
>
> He is **pretending** that he didn't know anything.
>   He is **faking** that he didn't know anything.
>   He is **acting like** he didn't know anything.

Comment: This is the sentence: `He's pretending that he didn't know anything. He is (faker, self-denial, deluded)`.

Comment: I have added to my answer responding to your comment. Being **deluded** and **in self-denial** might be the result of **pretending not to know**.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!